# Does the Bohr atomic model relate to the $spdf$ electron shell model?

Tags: atomic-physics, atoms, orbitals

I am in a structures of materials class and the Bohr model was brought up. Chemistry's azimuthal electron energy level does not seem to support this. What am I not seeing?

Comment: The Bohr model is just too basic to contain orbitals. They don't seem to support each other because, well, they just don't.

Comment: thanks. sounds like the bohr model is just simplified and wrong.

Answer (score 2):

P.S. This answer is with **corrections made after** the first comment below.

I would like to add some more details to @knzhou's comment.

The Bohr model is the most basic quantum model of the atom. I do not know how familiar you are with quantum mechanics, but say if you solve the Schrödinger Equation for the Hydrogen atom, you will see the equation separating into the *radial* and *angular* parts.

The solution to the *radial* part of the equation will give us the *radial wave functions* $R_n(r)$ where $n$ denotes the *principal quantum numbers*. These solutions exist only for the Bohr energies. Now, when you take the radial wave function and calculate the *most probable radius* (i.e., the radial value at which the (radial) probability density $P_n(r)=|R_n(r)|^2$ is maximized) it would turn out to be the same as the Bohr radius.

The solution to the *angular* part will depend on the quantum numbers $l,m$ for the subshells and orbitals.

Comment: "Bohr orbits come up as one part of the solution" - this is either wrong or extremely misleading. The solutions of the hydrogenic time-independent Schrödinger equation are wavefunctions that are spread over all possible radii. Unless and until you specify exactly how you extract "orbits" from wavefunctions, and in what sense you understand the former, the statement doesn't even begin to make sense as stated.

Comment: I agree that it is misleading. I should clarify that a bit more, and edit the answer. Extremely sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

The Bohr model had only circular orbits. There is the semi-classical Bohr-Sommerfeld model where orbits with the same energy can have different angular momentum. https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Sommerfeld_ellipses.svg

[image: Bohr-Sommerfeld ellipses for $n=5$]

Comment: ... and, as always: any discrepancies between the Bohr model and reality (as embodied in full-blown quantum mechanics) are real and they are there because the Bohr model is an incomplete and obsolete model of reality that is only good for historical purposes.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty The model is useful, for example to understand the connection to the classical limit. And to understand why the $2s$ levels are more strongly bound than $2p$ levels in larger atoms.

Comment: I would tend to dispute that but for some uses it does check out. However, I think it's important to add the caveat to try and prevent attitudes like the ones [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/220742) or [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/362239): if the Bohr model checks out, then good, but if it doesn't, then so much the worse for the model - but that fact can get lost in the telling and it is our responsibility to make the communication clear on that point.